# Angular 5; asp.net web api http.delete doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular5

I have asp.net web api server run in debug made and separate project uses Angular 5 - 5.2.11.

I try to delete data and I can't, but when I use postman it work.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class UserService { private getUserSucess: any;

  private  _headers =  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  };

  private headers={
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  deletUserHttp() {
    return this.http.delete( 'http://localhost:52817/api/users/1' ).subscribe(deleteSucess.bind(this), deleteError.bind(this));


 function deleteSucess(resp) {
   debugger;
   return resp;
 }
 function deleteError(resp) {
  //resp = HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, 
  debugger;
  return resp;
 }
}
```

I also try with: `this._headers` and `this.headars` the result was the same:

> HttpErrorResponse { headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false,
>
> 405 Method Not Allowed:
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:52817/api/users/1
>      Request Method: OPTIONS
>      Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
>      Remote Address: [::1]:52817
>      Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>      Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
>      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>      Allow: GET,PUT,DELETE
>      Cache-Control: no-cache
>      Content-Length: 71
>      Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>      Date: Sat, 16 Jun 2018 05:43:07 GMT
>      Expires: -1
>      Pragma: no-cache
>      Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>      X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>      X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>      X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?
>        QzpcVXNlcnNcQmV0bWlyYVxzb3VyY2VccmVwb3NcVXNlcnNcVXNlcnNcYXBpXHVzZXJzXDE=?=
>      Accept: */*
>      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>      Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6
>      Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
>        Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
>        Connection: keep-alive
>        Host: localhost:52817
>        Origin: http://localhost:4200
>        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36

`web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />       
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />    
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?://((.+\.)?domain1\.com|(.+\.)?domain2\.com|(.+\.)?domain3\.com))" />
                </conditions>
                <!--<match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Methods" pattern="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?://((.+\.)?domain1\.com|(.+\.)?domain2\.com|(.+\.)?domain3\.com))" />
                </conditions>-->
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
...
```

Please help me because I really don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for enabling CORS for your asp.net webapi. Once CORS is enabled you should be able to delete using Angular app.